# Meaning of an empty line in Python source code file

Tags: python

Will a Python program have exactly the same meaning if I will remove all empty lines from all my source files everywhere, like instead of:

```
def foo():
    x = 1

    if True:
        bar()
```

I will do:

```
def foo():
    x = 1
    if True:
        bar()
```

Everywhere means **EVERYWHERE** here. In class definitions, after import statements, etc.

Please do not comment on style and aesthetics. This is a different topic. Same to entering code right into the interpreter. This question is about the source code files.

The similar questions is about adding empty lines. Can I add them in between **ANY** two lines of code without changing the semantics?

Unfortunately docs are not very explicit here.

Comment: I can't think of a situation where a blank line in between two lines would make a difference personally.

Comment: @Loocid In a multiline string.

Comment: @HeapOverflow Ah yep, that's definitely one!

Comment: Literal strings have different rules in all other languages too. This question about the core grammar.

Comment: @Web-Intern Huh?

Answer (score 2):

If I claim an invalid encoding in the third line after two empty lines, it runs fine:

```
# -*- coding: foobar -*-
```

If I remove one or both of the empty lines, this happens:

```
SyntaxError: encoding problem: foobar with BOM
```

That's because Python looks for an encoding only in the first two lines. Of course it doesn't have to be an *invalid* encoding. You also get a difference for a *valid* encoding other than the default encoding, as the file will be decoded differently then. Again depending on whether it's in the first two lines or not, so empty lines can make a difference there.

See [Encoding declarations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations) and also the rest of that page, including [Blank lines](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#blank-lines).

Comment: Thanks. Feel free to delete your comment. I will delete mine after that.

Answer (score 1):

That will be fine. Python is picky about tabbing but doesn't care whether or not you include blank lines in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It won't make a difference in a script except in multi line strings. However, when you are entering code directly into the interpreter, it uses blank lines to detect the end of blocks of code (`for` loops, function definitions, etc.), so you may get errors.